# The search bar cant search data across all pages in the table

Tags: pagination, searchbar

Is there a code used for search bar that can search data across all pages? I insert pagination in my table where it display all data, but then I only search data that was on the current page. I tried java script but still not working.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        const searchInput = document.getElementById('searchInput');
        const rows = document.querySelectorAll('tbody tr');
        const noClientsFoundMessage = document.getElementById('noClientsFoundMessage');

        // Function to filter clients based on search input
        function filterClients() {
            const searchValue = searchInput.value.trim().toLowerCase();
            let countVisibleRows = 0;

            rows.forEach(row => {
                const clientName = row.dataset.clientName.toLowerCase();
                if (clientName.includes(searchValue)) {
                    row.style.display = '';
                    countVisibleRows++;
                } else {
                    row.style.display = 'none';
                }
            });

            // Show "No matching clients found" message if no clients match the search query
            noClientsFoundMessage.style.display = countVisibleRows === 0 ? 'block' : 'none';
        }

        searchInput.addEventListener('input', filterClients);

        // Clear search input
        $('.clear-search-btn').click(function () {
            searchInput.value = '';
            filterClients();
        });

        // Trigger search on page load to show all clients initially
        filterClients();
    });
```